# ul's li background color onmouseover with ribbon

Tags: html, css, background, html-lists

I have the menu:
[JSFIDDLE LINK](http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/1967/n6og3.jpg)

and i would like when someone over with the mouse on some of the first list item, the background will change to blue and will be like of this (a bit more bigger with):

[Image of sample](http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/1967/n6og3.jpg)

Thanks a lot!
Tal.

Comment: your jsfiddle link also contains image.

Comment: there is no jsfiddle link, its the same image from your sample

Comment: its hover not over and search and use css hover property.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655027/how-to-put-image-outside-of-its-parent-div-when-hover Here is a same question but img instead of li

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use css `box-shadow` property :

```
a
{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 grey;
    background-color: grey;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
a:hover
{
    background-color: #004890;
    box-shadow: 0 -8px 0 #004890;
    color: white;
}
```

Exemple : [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/henatezu/4/edit)